# unable to add IPSec IKEv2 profile on Fedora 22/23

Tags: networking, fedora, gnome, networkmanager, ipsec

it should be something really simple, but I cannot add IPSec IKEv2 profile in Network Manager settings, Add button is greyed out.

Does anyone know?
[image: Actual dialog box with "Add" greyed out]

[image: Strongswan packages have been added, configuration is available]

Answer (score 0):

same problem across all Linux distros

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-strongswan/+bug/1448879

https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=944769

except that nobody seems to care about Fedora.